# Replication to subscriber with different name

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to set up the following replication scenarios?

1. Replication between 2 servers with different database name. For example, replicate **FROM** server_A (primary) database name `primary_product` **TO** server_B (slave) database name `primary_product_analytics`
2. Replication between 2 servers which consist of several databases in Server_A, need to be transferred into single database with multiple schemas (custom schema name) on Server_B.

I have successfully setup replication using WAL but I would like guidance on implementing the above scenarios if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WAL-based replication is *physical* replication, i.e., it replicates all the changes made on the disk of a database cluster. In other words, all databases and their contents are exactly the same.

If you want replicate with different database names, you can use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html), which replicates changes made to specified tables.

However, logical replication cannot change the schema name. If you want to copy changes to a table in a different schema, you could do it manually with triggers and [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Comment: Can please you elaborate on how to "do it manually with triggers and postgres_fdw"?

Comment: @GunarGessner "Manually" means that you have to write and add triggers for every operation on every table.