# Logical Replication to different schema name

Tags: postgresql, replication

We have PostgreSQL 11 database with structure one database one schema (public).

```
dbname : production_one
schema : public

dbname : production_two
schema : public
```

I would like to set up a logical replication, so that it will have structure One database, multiple schema as below:

```
dbname : prod_slave
schema : prod_one, prod_two
```

is it possible to do logical replication as above?

I have successful replication using streaming replication, but the situation need us to use logical replication as above.

Comment: Is this the same probelm as [Replication to subscriber with different name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227628/replication-to-subscriber-with-different-name)?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the situation is the same

Answer (score 8):

This does not seem to be possible with built-in logical replication: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-subscription.html

> The tables are matched between the publisher and the subscriber using
>   the fully qualified table name. Replication to differently-named
>   tables on the subscriber is not supported.

Since it uses fully qualified names, a different schema would count as a different name, and is not supported.

pub/sub is just a user friendly wrapping around a [more general facility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html), you might be able to create decoding plugins to give you finer control.  I doubt that doing so is for the faint of heart, though.

Answer (score 2):

this feature is scheduled on PostgreSQL 15

> Logical replication
> support for publishing all tables of a schema added (commit 5a283246)

https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=5a2832465fd8984d089e8c44c094e6900d987fcd

> Allow publishing the tables of schema.
>
> A new option "FOR ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA" in Create/Alter Publication
> allows one or more schemas to be specified, whose tables are selected
> by the publisher for sending the data to the subscriber.
>
> The new syntax allows specifying both the tables and schemas. For
> example: CREATE PUBLICATION pub1 FOR TABLE t1,t2,t3, ALL TABLES IN
> SCHEMA s1,s2; OR ALTER PUBLICATION pub1 ADD TABLE t1,t2,t3, ALL TABLES
> IN SCHEMA s1,s2;
>
> A new system table "pg_publication_namespace" has been added, to
> maintain the schemas that the user wants to publish through the
> publication. Modified the output plugin (pgoutput) to publish the
> changes if the relation is part of schema publication.
>
> Updates pg_dump to identify and dump schema publications. Updates the
> \d family of commands to display schema publications and \dRp+ variant
> will now display associated schemas if any

Comment: PG 15 is out and the docs still say "Replication to differently-named tables on the subscriber is not supported"

Comment: This commit that @Piotr Kolodziez is reffering to, I have the impression that discribed something totaly different. It describes the possibility to specify a schema (from including all tables contained there) instead a list of tables or a single table

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the schemas in the original databases to `prod_one` and `prod_two` instead of `public` would seem to be the only possibility here.

Answer (score 0):

As [@jjanes mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227922/67785) it is not possible.

But I think, creating a typical 'Logical Replication' in different databases and then using foreign data wrappers to link databases in one database, but in different schemas, would be the most simple solution, but not much better than replicating tables in one database's different schemas.